# C++ Large 2D array (on the heap) crashes the application

Tags: c++, arrays

So basically I'm trying to create a large 2D array ([66049][66049]) of floats, but for some reason the application crashes AS it is allocating memory on the heap. Here is how I allocate it:

```
float **heights;
heights = new float*[numVertices];
for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++)
    {
        heights[i] = new float[numVertices];
    }
```

I tried adding a print of i in the for loop to check when it crashes and i is around 7200 (not always same number) when it crashes.

Could I be using too much memory? If so how else could I do this without the application crashing.

Thanks.

Comment: ***Could I be using too much memory?*** Yes. I believe its over 17GB of memory. Are you compiling for 64 bits? Do you have more than 17GB of virtual memory?

Comment: It's called a debugger for a reason. Switch it to debug and figure out what the error is, and if you can't figure it out, then include it in your post.

Comment: Also, like @drescherjm said, you are probably using too much memory. I got 17449.881604 MB that would be allocated for that, and there's a good chance your system won't support it.

Comment: Do you really need every position? Perhaps a sparse array would work?

Comment: Around 7200 arrays of around 66000 floats is about 2 gigabytes.

Comment: ***If so how else could I do this without the application crashing.*** Difficult to give a detailed answer since you have not described why you need a 66049 by 66049 array of floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was using too much memory, way too much. I only needed [257][257] in the end, not [257*257][257*257], so it was my bad.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using too much memory.
So, if operator `new` can't allocate memory for some reasons (it's not enough of free memory, for example), it throws an exception `std::bad_alloc`.
Use try-catch block to detect thrown exceptions, like this:

```
try{
   float **heights;
   heights = new float*[numVertices];
   for (int i = 0; i < numVertices; i++){
      heights[i] = new float[numVertices];
   }
}
catch(std::exception exc){ std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl; }
system("pause");
```

Also, read some articles about [std::bad_alloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) and [operator new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)